# VirtualBox Version 6.1.40 breaks Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS guest's mouse scrolling

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, mouse, touchpad

After the latest upgrade to VirtualBox 6.1.40 on my Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS installation the mouse scrolling does not work anymore. Guest additions and extension pack were all upgraded as well. So all is up to date. The scroll wheel works sometimes, but usually not at all. Disabling mouse pointer integration fixes the issue, but leads to other issues and of course it's not very nice in a multi screen setup. I tried switching between libinput and evdev in the X.org.conf, but that changed nothing.

Comment: You have Ubuntu Core 20 in the title and the tag Ubuntu 20.04 Which one is correct?

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect the correct version: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem today when I upgraded to 6.1.40. I upgraded to 7.0.2 and that problem went away. I am now getting another unrelated problem so I am probably going back to 6.1.38 until these issues get resolved. I'd suggest giving 7.0.2 a try if it's available for you.

The issue with 7.0.2 is that guest additions moving windows around (`x11`) causes the background to refresh less frequently (about 700ms). Also, after a few minutes of use my environment slows down to a crawl (as in, it feels sluggish and actions are delayed).

Comment: Cool. Any details on what issue 7.0.2 was giving you? I might try ouy 7.0.2 then... not having scroll wheel really sucks. Interesting enough not all apps behave the same. Emacs seems fine with scrolling, but I hardly use it there, but Chrome scrolling is totally broken.